# Recuperar um ID e inserir no ComboBox para alterardados

Tags: php, mysql

O que eu preciso fazer é recuperar o id e inseri-lo no combobox para poder alterar os dados mas o combobox fica vazio não sei porque, se alguém puder me ajudar eu agradeço.

Recupera os Dados do Banco

```
<?php
   session_start();
    $ID_Cliente = $_SESSION['ID_Cliente'];


    $conexao = mysql_connect("localhost:3306","root","root") or die("Erro durante a conexão do banco de dados");
    mysql_select_db("prestadora",$conexao);
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $conexao);
    mysql_query('SET character_set_connection=utf8', $conexao);
    mysql_query('SET character_set_client=utf8', $conexao);
    mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8', $conexao);
    $consulta= "select * from pedido where ClienteID_Cliente='$ID_Cliente' " ;
    $resultado=mysql_query($consulta,$conexao) or die ("Não foi possível Consultar os seus dados.");
    mysql_close($conexao);


      while($consulta=mysql_fetch_array($resultado)){

        $Tipo_Servico=$consulta["Tipo_Servico"];
        $DataVisita=$consulta["DataVisita"];
        $HoraVisita=$consulta["HoraVisita"];
        $EnderecoVisita=$consulta["EnderecoVisita"];          
        $ID_Pedido=$consulta["ID_Pedido"];    


      }

?>
```

Formulario do Alterar

```
<header id="cabecalho">
    <img src="_imagens/logo.jpg">
</header>
<br class="fixFloat">
<nav id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html" target="_self">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="cadastra-se.html" target="_self">Cadastra-se</a></li>
        <li><a href="login.html" target="_self">Login</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>



<section id="form">
    <fieldset id="form_field">
        <legend id="form_legend">Alterar Pedido</legend>

        <?php
        include "_php/listarpedido.php";
        ?>

              <form method="post" action="_php/alterarpedido.php">
                 Escolher qual alterar<select name="ID_Pedido">
                 <option value="<?php echo $ID_Pedido;?>"></option> </select><br/><br/>
                 Tipo de Serviço: <select name="Tipo_Servico"  value="<?php echo $Tipo_Servico;?>">
                 <option name="Reforma Predial">Reforma Predial</option>
                 <option name="Jardinagem">Jardinagem</option>
                 <option name="Eletricista">Eletricista</option>
                 <option name="Encanador">Encanador</option>
                 </select> 
                 Data de Visita: <input type="text" name="DataVisita" value="<?php echo $DataVisita;?>">  
                 Hora de Visita: <input type="text" name="HoraVisita" value="<?php echo $HoraVisita;?>"><br/><br/>
                 Endereço de Visita: <input type="text" name="EnderecoVisita" value="<?php echo $EnderecoVisita;?>" >
                <fieldset id="form_field">
                      <legend id="form_legend">Alterar</legend>
                      <input type="submit" id="botao" value="Alterar">
                      <input type="reset" id="botao" value="Resetar">
                </fieldset>
            </form>

</section>


</body>
</html>
```

Alterar no Banco

```
<header id="cabecalho">
    <img src="../_imagens/Logo.jpg">
</header>
<br class="fixFloat">
<nav id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="../index.html" target="_self">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="../cadastra-se.html" target="_self">Cadastra-se</a></li>
        <li><a href="../login.html" target="_self">Login</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>


<section id="form">
    <?php

    $ID_Pedido=$_POST["ID_Pedido"];
    $Tipo_Servico=$_POST["$Tipo_Servico"];
    $DataVisita=$_POST["DataVisita"];
    $HoraVisita=$_POST["HoraVisita"];
    $EnderecoVisita=$_POST["EnderecoVisita"];




    $conexao = mysql_connect("localhost:3306","root","root") or die("Erro durante a conexão do banco de dados");
    mysql_select_db("prestadora",$conexao);
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $conexao);
    mysql_query('SET character_set_connection=utf8', $conexao);
    mysql_query('SET character_set_client=utf8', $conexao);
    mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8', $conexao);
    $atualiza= "update cliente set Tipo_Servico='$Tipo_Servico',DataVisita='$DataVisita',HoraVisita='$HoraVisita',EnderecoVisita='$EnderecoVisita' WHERE ID_Pedido='$ID_Pedido'" ;
    mysql_query($atualiza,$conexao) or die ("Não foi possível executar a atualização.");
    mysql_close($conexao);



    echo"<fieldset id='form_field'><legend id='form_legend'>Dados do Pedido</legend>
  <p>Dados do Pedido Alterados com Sucesso !!!</p></fieldset>";



    ?>
<fieldset id="form_field">
     <legend id="form_legend">Voltar</legend>
    <a href="../menucliente.html" id="botao">Voltar</a>
</fieldset>

</section>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Onde esta sua duvida exatamente, nao ta faltando um js ai nao?

Comment: nesse trecho "Escolher qual alterar<select name="ID_Pedido">
     <option value="<?php echo $ID_Pedido;?>"></option> </select><br/><br/>";

Comment: ele fica vazio o combobox,não recebe as id do banco

Comment: Tmb nao tem validacoes o server le todas indormacoes mesmo que nao seja post e faz a query mysql. Outra se vc estiver apenas atualizando um sistema que ja esta escrito e tem um php menor que o 5.6 ai tudo bem. Senao sugiro vc atualizar seu php.

Comment: Fica vazio pq vc nao mandou exibir nada. Tenta ver o source HTML impresso pelo browser. Garanto que no select o campo value esta com o id. Porem no form nao vai aparecer nada pq nao ta mandando imprimí nada. Tem que mandar exibir o id ou o nome dentro da tag option

Comment: mas ta aqui <option value="<?php echo $ID_Pedido;?>"></option>

Comment: Faça `<option value="<?php echo $ID_Pedido;?>"><?php echo $ID_Pedido;?></option>`. Lembre-se que o `value` do *option* não é exibido e sim aquilo que está entre as tags.

Comment: agora ta exibindo o numero 3 que é o terceiro registro de id mas não exibe todos os id cadastro na tabela

Comment: ou melhor dizendo não exibe os demais,o resto dos id da tabela

Comment: Ai voce tem q implementar outra sql com os dados e fazer um loop

Comment: e faria o que para mudar os outros atributos quando eu mudasse o ID do combobox ?

Comment: Ai tenta com ajax ou jQuery.

Comment: tem algum turtorial ou algum exemplo parecido ??. Para eu seguir porque isso ai eu não conheço nada ainda, estou em processo de aprendizagem kkkk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agora sim. Voce deve mandar exibir dentro da tag option assim

```
<option value="<?php echo $id;?>"><?php echo $id;?></option>
```

Comment: se vc estiver usando o chrome tente usar as ferrementas do desenvolvedor e vc vai ver no html que a tag option tem valor mas esta vazia para exibir o nome no browser algo assim: `<option value="587"></option>`